# drop down automate xpath clarification using selenium webdriver - salesforce application

Tags: jquery, xpath, selenium-webdriver, salesforce

[image]Application developed in salesforce and below is the code for an dropdown box, all the items in the drop down they build with `<li>` tag, but i dont know how to pick a particular item with this design.

```
<div id="Department__cformControl" class="slds-form-element">
    <div id="Department__c" class="slds-picklist" data-aljs="picklist" aria-expanded="true">
        <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-picklist__label cusPicklistBtn" aria-haspopup="true">
            <span class="slds-truncate">
                None
            </span>
            <svg class="slds-icon" aria-hidden="true">
                <use xlink:href="/resource/1475922714000/slds/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#down"></use>
            </svg>
        </button>
        <div class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown--left slds-dropdown--menu slds-hide">
            <ul class="slds-dropdown__list" role="menu">
                <li id="menu0" class="slds-dropdown__item slds-is-selected" href="#"> … </li>
                    <a role="menuitemradio" href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <p class="slds-truncate">
                            <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right--x-small" aria-hidden="true">
                                <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></use>
                            </svg>
                        Information Technology
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu1" class="slds-dropdown__item" href="#"> … </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my expected : i want to choose the item Information Technology

in the normal drop down i can easily choose the item using select e.g :`new Select(sourceDropDown).selectByVisibleText(Value);`

but please clarify how can i choose the item?

Comment: Are you sure it is drop down? can you post the screenshot of the UI how it looks?

Comment: Yes its drop down , click the icon and its open then choose the item attached the UI

Comment: As per my knowledge, we can use `Select class` for `SELECT TAGS`. reference https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html. Are you sure `Select class` can be used for `ul - li` elements?

Comment: `Select()` can be applied to `<select>` elements only. In your case you can use simple `click()` to open drop-down and same to select required option

Answer (score 0):

The role="menu" makes me think it's meant to be used as a drop-down menu.  usually drop-down menus do not require a click to pull-down the options, just hovering the mouse cursor over the menu should activate it.  If that's the case, your best bet is to use either Selenium Actions class or javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have clicked on the drop down, you can select the option `Information Technology`by clicking on control having following xpath:

```
//li/a/p[text()='Information Technology']
```